How to find the slope of the lower region in any curve?
Github link to txt file`So I have a project , of which the data are of atomic force microscopy. I have two values d = distance and f = force plotted on a normal x-y graph. So there will curves of slightly differnt shapes and values but will look somehow the same.
I am using numpy and using sliding window method unfortuantely it does not work ans the proffesor told me in one curve the data points are increasing and on the other the data points are dereasing. My sample code is :
def find_linear_part(d, f, window_size=120, min_slope=0.01):
    slope = 0
    intercept = 0
    fit = 0
    min_residual = float('inf')

    for i in range(len(d) - window_size + 1):
        d_window = d[i:i + window_size]
        f_window = f[i:i + window_size]
        slope, intercept = np.polyfit(d_window, f_window, 1)
        y_fit = slope * d_window + intercept
        residual = np.sum((f_window - y_fit) ** 2)
        if residual < min_residual:
            min_residual = residual
            fit = (d_window, f_window)
            new_slope = slope
            new_intercept = intercept

    return fit, new_slope, new_intercept


I used here a threshold for the slope as some of the slopes were mentioned on the graph .`
and those are images of the expected graphs for instance.



Welcome to SO, please publish your data as well as a formatted code or shared link (no screenshot).

What does "the slope of the lower region" mean? If you mean the minimum point of the curve and the curve is smooth, you might just get away with find_linear_part = lambda: 0 ;-)

ok i know there is a confusion but what should I upload to understand better as screenshots are not allowed so the understanding is better ?

Screenshots of code/data are not allowed. Images/graphs that illustrate the expected logic are welcome.

Indeed I added the graphs but then removed them.

Also make sure to provide the expected output

Had dded the graphs and those graphs are the expected output.

You should also provide the underlying data in a reproducible format

added everything now
